# Exact same file and code. So why does the binary of my docx file always end differently?

Tags: asp-classic, httprequest, binaryfiles, docx

We take a (non-corrupted) .docx file from our server and post it via httprequest to an API.  When downloading it from the API it comes out corrupted. I 99% sure that this is down to the code that posts the file, not the API.

It turns out the corrupted file had some extra characters in the binary - I thought it would be pretty easy to find out where they came from and remove them. Boy was I wrong.

I've since realised that every time we post the file, the binary ending is slightly different.  We're using the **exact** same file, using the **exact** same code.

*What could account for this difference?*

**Example Binary Endings**

```
0015 e88a 5060 0700 00da 3b00 000f 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0060 1d00 0077
6f72 642f 7374 796c 6573 2e78 6d6c 504b
0506 0000 0000 0b00 0b00
```

30 seconds later:

```
0015 e88a 5060 0700 00da 3b00 000f 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0060 1d00 0077
6f72 642f 7374 796c 6573 2e78 6d6c 504b
0506 0000 0000 0b00 0b00 c102 00
```

Another 30 seconds later:

```
0015 e88a 5060 0700 00da 3b00 000f 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0060 1d00 0077
6f72 642f 7374 796c 6573 2e78 6d6c 504b
0506 0000 0000 0b00 0b00 c102 0000 ed24
```

**Posting Code**

```
Sub PostTheFile(CVFile, fullFilePath, PostToURL)

    strBoundary = "---------------------------9849436581144108930470211272"
    strRequestStart = "--" & strBoundary & vbCrlf &_
        "Content-Disposition: attachment; name=""file""; filename=""" & CVFile & """" & vbcrlf & vbcrlf
    strRequestEnd = vbCrLf & "--" & strBoundary & "--" 

    Set stream = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        stream.Type = adTypeBinary 
        stream.Mode = adModeReadWrite     
        stream.Open
        stream.Write StringToBinary(strRequestStart)
        stream.Write ReadBinaryFile(fullFilePath)
        stream.Write StringToBinary(strRequestEnd)
        stream.Position = 0
        BINARYPOST= stream.read
        stream.Close

    Set stream = Nothing    

    Set httpRequest = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
        httpRequest.Open "PATCH", PostToURL, False, "username", "pw"
        httpRequest.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=""" & strBoundary & """"
        httpRequest.Send BINARYPOST
        Response.write "httpRequest.status: " & httpRequest.status 
    Set httpRequest = Nothing   
End Sub


Function StringToBinary(input)
    dim stream
    set stream = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        stream.Charset = "UTF-8"
        stream.Type = adTypeText 
        stream.Mode = adModeReadWrite 
        stream.Open
        stream.WriteText input
        stream.Position = 0
        stream.Type = adTypeBinary 
        StringToBinary = stream.Read
        stream.Close
    set stream = Nothing
End Function

Function ReadBinaryFile(fullFilePath) 
    dim stream
    set stream = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        stream.Type = 1
        stream.Open()
        stream.LoadFromFile(fullFilePath)
        ReadBinaryFile = stream.Read()
        stream.Close
    set stream = nothing
end function
```

**Update**

We played with a few different boundaries and Charsets.

There was some additional BOM stuff going on with UTF-8.

http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark‎

Now the issue is clearly the addition of (a seemingly random amount of) NULL / zero padding.

E.g. The first time it adds 13 sets of "00".  Hit refresh and the second time it will add 8.  A third time it adds 7.  Each time with the exact same file and code.

**Suggestion - How Likely is This?**

The destination URL for the post is https - so a friend suggested that our server may have recognised this and added random padding as part of the encryption. This sounds kind of unlikely to me, but I don't have any better suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a similar question:

[Error in downloaded pdf file - ASP classic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17828299/error-in-downloaded-pdf-file-asp-classic)

Here are some tips that come from there:

- set Stream .Mode property to 3
- set Response.ContentType to "xxx/xxx"
- **Before you start adding Response Headers, you should call Response.Clear (just to be sure you're not sending extra markup)** (This seems very similar)

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: Hi again :)  thank you for your persistent assistance. We set the stream.mode property to 3 (adModeReadWrite).  

The Content-Type throws an error at the API if it is set to anything other than "multipart/form-data".  

I have come across the Response.Clear suggestion, but I don't understand how it would be applied to our context. It makes sense when sending a stream to a browser, but not when posting it using httpRequest.

Comment: What's the length of BINARYCODE before sending ? and after sending ?

Comment: The length is the same at each of 3 stages - 1. immediately after the BINARYPOST variable is set, 2. immediately before posting the data, and 3. immediately after posting the data.

Comment: And please see update above - after resolving a BOM issue, the problem now appears to be just NULL/zero padding.